# How should a user with a problem contact a moderator?

Tags: support, faq, moderators

I am a user, and I have a problem. I want to contact a moderator to discuss it further. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

To contact a site moderator, you can

- Reply to a message received from the "moderator message" system. The only "trick" on the mod message system is that the messages need to be done in turns, alternated between mod team and user. That means that if the mod team does not send a reply back to the user, the user will not be able to message the team again. The limit is in place to prevent abuse. This option is available even to users who are suspended.
- Flag a post or comment with a custom flag. This option is most suitable when you have a concern with the specific post or comment.
- Post a question on meta. This option is most suitable if you have a concern that you think requires community discussion.
- Post a brief message in the Academia chat room, asking the moderators to set up a private chat and continue a conversation with you there. This option is suitable for private real-time communication with one or more moderators.

If that doesn't work out to your satisfaction, you can use the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page on the site to reach out to a StackExchange employee.

Comment: I think it should be emphasized that before posting a question on meta or calling a moderator, users should search well for possibly similar issues which are discussed previously on website or duplicate ones. Also most of the times; there is no need to attract moderators attention to a problem; users on the site will be happy to help other users if they are able to or have enough privileges. Actually, as FAQ it may be worth to open a question entitled "For which issues should I contact moderators?" and in an answer it become clear that some issues can be solved by users with enough privileges.